# Using index for jsonb sub keys postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like:

```
create table items
(
    id int constraint items_pk primary key,
    acl jsonb
);
```

With such items:

```
id,acl
1,{
    "users": {
        "2": { <-- The key "2" is the user_id
            "role1": {...}, 
            "role2": {...}
        },
        "3": {
            "role1": {...}
        }
    },
    "groups": {...}
}
...
```

I want to count the number of items where the user "2" has the role "role2", what I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE ( acl->'users'->'2' ? 'role2')
```

The problem is that I want this query to use an index, but I can't make this query to use them. Here are the index I setup:

```
CREATE INDEX _index1 ON items using gin (acl jsonb_ops);
CREATE INDEX _index2 ON items using gin ((acl->'users') jsonb_ops);
```

Then I tried this query that is using the index but it is slower ( like 40x ) than the first one so it is unuseful. And also goes beyond the fact that I just want to verify the presence of the "role2" key in acl->'users'->'2'.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE ( acl @> '{"users": {"2": {"role2": {...}}}}');
```

My question is how can I make this query to use an index keeping my current json data structure ?

I know I can use string arrays and lots of other things to make this usecase work but they imply changing the data structure, and this is not my point here because the problem is that this data structure is used at scale and I want to know if something is possible with this structure.

Comment: The query you report as using the index is a syntax error.

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` plan for the query using the index (as well as the true text of that query), and the query not using the index.

Comment: What is `{...}` actually? Does the empty object `{}`  work there?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE ( acl @> '{"users": {"2": {"role2": {}}}}');` should do what you want. If that is also slow with the index, please give us the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.